# HTML table row height

Tags: asp.net, html, css

HTML & CSS Question:

I'm trying to confine my table row to one line only (5 mm height, 30 mm length).
But it should stay that size, even if it doesn't fit in this space (because else i get problems with the gradient background image size - looking horible).

How can I do that?

//GRS/Standorte/G08 Zürich Schindlerstrasse/Standortdaten/Gebäudedaten/E01/Trakt 2/Sicherheitsdokumentationen/*.*







Abc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Saar already said, you can try `white-space: nowrap` to keep all text in one line. Add `overflow:hidden` to prevent content growing uncontrollably to the right (You may have to insert a `div` into the `td` for that to work, not sure whether `td` respects overflow: hidden.) It should work as long as there are no line breaks or block elements in the content.

This is never going to be a 100% foolproof solution, though. The user may have selected a larger font size, overstretching the cell even if there's only one line.

I don't know what your image looks like, but how about repeating it only horizontalle (`background-repeat: repeat-x`) and filling the rest up with a background color? That usually helps.

Answer (score 1):

Set "overflow" to "hidden" and define the width&height of your row

Answer (score 0):

try css property

```
white-space: nowrap;
```